# How to get the first object from an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, object, observablecollection

I would like to get the first object in an ObservableCollection like this:

```
Customer pCustomer = new Customer();
pCustomer = this.CustomerDataObject.First;

public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerDataObject
{
    get
    {
        return mCustomerDataObject;
    }
}
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: In addition to what has been answered: ObservableCollection implements the interface `IList<T>` and hence has an indexer. Provided that the collection contains at least one element, you may get the first element by `CustomerDataObject[0]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`First` is not a property it is an extension method.

```
var first = CustomerDataObject.First();
```

If no element, [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will throw exception, You can use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in that case which will return null.

```
var firstOrDefault = CustomerDataObject.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: These extension methods are part of LINQ, make sure to use the Linq namespace: `using System.Linq;`